# String grouping (aggregation) with data.table (R 3.1.1)

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

**Input:** I have this data:

```
library(data.table)
ids <- c(10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12)
items <- c('soup', 'rice', 'lemon', 'chicken', 'lamb', 'noodles')
orders <- as.data.table(list(id=ids, item=items))

> orders
   id    item
1: 10    soup
2: 10    rice
3: 10   lemon
4: 11 chicken
5: 12    lamb
6: 12 noodles
```

**Goal:** Need to arrive at this (group all items by their id):

```
   id        items
1: 10    soup,rice,lemon
2: 11    chicken
3: 12    lamb,noodles
```

**What I did:** I am using data.table on R 3.1.1 (latest release) - tried the below method, which should work:

```
orders[,list(items=list(item)), by=id]
```

But getting the below (incorrect) output:

```
   id       items
1: 10 lamb,noodles,lemon
2: 11 lamb,noodles,lemon
3: 12 lamb,noodles,lemon
```

What am I doing wrong, and what is the right way to group strings correctly with data.table?

Comment: What you mention about incorrect result in Rv3.1.1 was a [bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/481) that's been fixed in 1.9.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for what it sounds like you're looking for is a little bit awkward, but makes sense when you think about how you would normally use `list`.

Try the following:

```
orders[, list(item = list(item)), by = "id"]
#    id            item
# 1: 10 soup,rice,lemon
# 2: 11         chicken
# 3: 12    lamb,noodles
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ id  : num  10 11 12
#  $ item:List of 3
#   ..$ : chr  "soup" "rice" "lemon"
#   ..$ : chr "chicken"
#   ..$ : chr  "lamb" "noodles"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Cool - its working. Thank you. But it is confusing why c(item) is required, given that `item` is supposed to be already a vector (grouped by id). For example, this code snippet `orders[,str(item), by=id]` clearly indicates each as a vector correctly (and generates only 3 rows, one for each group, and not 6 rows, which would be the case if they were individual elements that need `c` to make them vector). Anyhow, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Also, thank you for `str(.Last.value)` - didn't know about it. Can be helpful to avoid re-executing the commands just to see the `str`.

Answer (score 4):

```
orders[, paste(item, collapse = ","), by = id]

##    id              V1
## 1: 10 soup,rice,lemon
## 2: 11         chicken
## 3: 12    lamb,noodles
```

Comment: Thank you David. Paste works, but it makes it difficult to individually identify the elements in the 'items' output afterwards (unlike a list). Perhaps I should have mentioned in the question that this is part of a library/package function I am creating and it should have the ability to individually identify the elements afterwards in the returned output (as a data-frame). I would love to go with paste, but as it yields a string and the caller has to 'parse' it, unlike a list which is more native for iteration or lapply kind of stuff. Would love to see similar result with list/dataframe magic

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem, so you're looking for a similar behavior as you would get with `aggregate(item ~ id, orders, I)`?